# Setup Oracle Database to connect and pull data from Microsoft Sharepoint site

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I want to transfer data from SharePoint site to a oracle database.

Please suggest me a recommended approach.

Comment: Can anyone plz suggest some solution on the same